# Unable to execute mysqldump with date condition in where clause

Tags: mysql

I am trying to take delta dump from MariaDB with following command:

```
 mysqldump --opt -h<HOST_NAME> -u<USER_ID> -p<PASSWORD> --no-create-info --where=date >= '2019-04-01' <DATABASE_NAME>  > backup.sql
```

I am getting following error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to
database '2019-04-01' when selecting the database
```

Can anyone please help me figuring out what mistake I am doing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--where` condition in the command you gave consists of several words separated by spaces. But the argument to the `--where` option must be one argument, at least as far as the shell interprets it.

So the argument `'2019-04-01' was interpreted as the database name, instead of part of your condition.

Try this:

```
mysqldump ... --where="date >= '2019-04-01'" <DATABASE_NAME> > backup.sql
```

The double-quotes will delimit the full expression and make the shell interpret it as a single argument.